# Задача симулятор лифта

Tags: java, задание-на-собеседовании

Задача на симулятор лифта, задача решена, все работает, но было отвергнуто словами что мне нужно подтянуть алгоритмы. Что под этим подразумевается, как еще можно решить задачу?

```
/**
 * Написать программу «симулятор лифта».
 * Программа запускается из коммандной строки, в качестве параметров задается:
 *      кол-во этажей в подъезде - N (от 5 до 20);
 *      высота одного этажа;
 *      скорость лифта при движении в метрах в секунду (ускорением пренебрегаем, считаем, что когда лифт едет - он сразу едет с определенной скоростью);
 *      время между открытием и закрытием дверей.
 *
 * После запуска программа должна постоянно ожидать ввода от пользователя и выводить действия лифта в реальном времени.
 * События, которые нужно выводить:
 * лифт проезжает некоторый этаж;
 * лифт открыл двери;
 * лифт закрыл двери.
 *
 * Возможный ввод пользователя:
 *       вызов лифта на этаж из подъезда;
 *       нажать на кнопку этажа внутри лифта.
 *
 * Считаем, что пользователь не может помешать лифту закрыть двери.
 * Все данные, которых не хватает в задаче можно выбрать на свое усмотрение.
 * В результате должен получиться компилируемый код (в случае с java предлагается писать код в одном файле).
 */

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Elevator elevator = new Elevator(20, 3, 2, 2);
        elevator.init();
    }

    private static class Elevator {
        private static final long MILLISECONDS = 100; //1000
        private final int doorTime;
        private final int floors;
        private final long floorSpeedSeconds;
        private int currentFloor = 1;

        private Elevator(int floors, int height, int speed, int doorTime) {
            this.doorTime = doorTime;
            this.floors = floors;
            floorSpeedSeconds = height / speed * MILLISECONDS;
        }

        private void init() throws InterruptedException {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                Command command = new Command(scanner.nextLine());
                if (command.targetFloor > floors) {
                    System.out.println("Target floor should be less than " + floors);
                    continue;
                }
                if (command.targetFloor > currentFloor) {
                    moveUp(command);
                } else if (command.targetFloor < currentFloor) {
                    moveDown(command);
                }
                currentFloor = command.targetFloor;
                openAndCloseDoor(doorTime);
            }
        }

        private void printCurrentFloor(int i) {
            System.out.println("Current floor is " + i);
        }

        private void openAndCloseDoor(int doorTime) throws InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("Open door");
            Thread.sleep(doorTime * MILLISECONDS);
            System.out.println("Close door");
        }

        private void moveDown(Command command) throws InterruptedException {
            for (int i = currentFloor; i >= command.targetFloor; i--) {
                Thread.sleep(floorSpeedSeconds);
                printCurrentFloor(i);
            }
        }

        private void moveUp(Command command) throws InterruptedException {
            for (int i = currentFloor; i <= command.targetFloor; i++) {
                Thread.sleep(floorSpeedSeconds);
                printCurrentFloor(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class Command {
        private final PressType type;
        private final int targetFloor;

        private Command(String type) {
            String[] commands = type.split(" ");
            this.type = PressType.type(commands[0]);
            this.targetFloor = parseInt(commands[1]);
        }
    }

    private enum PressType {
        IN("in"),
        OUT("out");

        private final String type;

        PressType(String type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        private static PressType type(String s) {
            return valueOf(s);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Первое - изучите поподробней структуры данных и дискретный анализ (не думал, что когда-либо об этом напишу)

Второе - изучите habr - там много обсуждений косяков, что вы совершили

Я бы, конечно, написал бы по-другому, но следует понимать, что в голову к экзаменатору не влезть, а мы здесь не Ванги или экстрасенсы. Возможно, мой бы вариант тоже был бы раскритикован.

Comment: Что то не верится что дикретный анализ помог в такой задаче. Можно ссылки на хабр статьи о которых вы говорите? не нашел

Comment: Задача же очень простая, мне даже очередь не нужна была, потому что все и так сохраняется в scanner

Comment: Я лично думаю что надо бы почитать SOLID. И сделать по первому принципу единственной ответственности. Почему то у вас сам лифт и ожидает команды и двигается. Сделайте так чтоб с минимальными изменениями программа могла получать команды из файла из консоли из космоса. По поводу алгоритмов я не думаю что они исходили из этой задачи.

Comment: да тут так-то немало ошибок: type не используется; при начале движения сначала происходит ожидание, а потом только выводится текущий этаж; `height / speed` вернёт целое значение, а не вещественное (1 вместо 1.5 для height == 3 и speed == 2) из-за чего получается неверное время на этаж; думаю ещё что-нибудь можно найти, если присмотреться

Comment: type да, не используется, вообще думаю не важно нажал человек снаружи лифта или изнутри. Интерьеру объяснил этот момент, на что мне сказал как хочешь

Comment: Момент с ожиданием, согласен. Что там ещё не правильного

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы сделал немножко по другому.

Для начала, там есть ремарка про реальное время, то есть, по идее, лифт должен кататься в своем потоке.

А если лифт в своем потоке и ещё принимает команды, то возникает вопрос синхронизации. Который легко решается, если команды выстроить в цепочку команд. Как это сделать? использовать `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`

Далее, нажатие на кнопку совсем не означает, что лифт вдруг ломанется на тот этаж. Лифт может быть уже в движении, когда на кнопку нажали, и он может ехать в противоположном направлении. То есть, по идее, нажатие на кнопку просто дает знать об этом лифту, но когда лифт туда поедет - отдельный вопрос.

Конечно, в идеале, надо ещё учитывать, куда человек ехать хочет (наверх или вниз) - наверное это имелось ввиду под нажатиеи из подъезда / из лифта. Это несложно сделать, но я не хочу усложнять пример.

По сути, самый простецкий вариант будет такой: При нажатии на кнопку, просто пометить этаж и добавить задачу лифту сгонять вверх и вниз по всем отмеченным этажам. Если лифт уже едет, и наткнется на отмеченный этаж - то остановится и откроет двери.

Код выгляит как то так (я в java не сильно разбираюсь, так что пардон если что не так)

```
class Elevator {
    private final long floorInterval;
    private final long waitingInterval;
    private int currentFloor = 0;
    private boolean[] floorButtons;
```

наш ExecutorService

```
    private ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public Elevator(int floors, long floorInterval, long waitingInterval) {
        this.floorInterval = floorInterval;
        this.waitingInterval = waitingInterval;
        this.floorButtons = new boolean[floors];
    }
```

Нажималка на кнопку

```
    public void buttonPressedForFloor(final int floor) {
        floorButtons[floor] = true;
        executor.submit(() -> {
            try {
                this.moveUp();
                this.moveDown();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Проверка необходимости движения вверх

```
    private void moveUp() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = currentFloor; i < floorButtons.length; i++)
            if (floorButtons[i]) {
                moveTo(i);
                return;
            }
    }
```

Проверка необходимости движения вниз

```
    private void moveDown() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = currentFloor; i > 0; i--)
            if (floorButtons[i]) {
                moveTo(i);
                return;
            }
    }
```

Само передвижение

```
    private void moveTo(int targetFloor) throws InterruptedException {
        int step = 1;
        if (targetFloor < currentFloor) step = -1;
        while (currentFloor != targetFloor) {
            Thread.sleep(floorInterval);
            currentFloor += step;
            sendMessage("CURRENT FLOOR: " + currentFloor);
            if (floorButtons[currentFloor]) {
                floorButtons[currentFloor] = false;
                doorOpenClose();
            }
        }
    }
```

Вспомогательный код

```
    private void doorOpenClose() throws InterruptedException {
        sendMessage("DOORS OPENED");
        Thread.sleep(waitingInterval);
        sendMessage("DOORS CLOSED");
    }

    private static void sendMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME) + " " + message);
    }

    public void stop() {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Запустить эту радость можно так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("input number of floors: ");
    int numOfFlors = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("input floor height (m): ");
    double floorHeight = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("input floor velocity (m/s): ");
    double floorVelocity = scanner.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("input floor doors time (seconds): ");
    long waitingInterval = scanner.nextLong() * 1000;

    long floorTime = (long) (1000.0 * floorHeight / floorVelocity);

    Elevator elevator = new Elevator(numOfFlors, floorTime, waitingInterval);

    scanner.nextLine();

    while (true) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if ("q".equals(line)) {
            elevator.stop();
            return;
        }
        try {
            int nextFloor = Integer.parseInt(line);
            if (nextFloor < 1 || nextFloor > numOfFlors) {
                System.out.println("Wrong floor. Try again.");
            } else {
                elevator.buttonPressedForFloor(nextFloor);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(line + " not a number");
        }
    }
}
```

Получается что то вроде такого

[image: ...]

Comment: только понял, что различать изнутри или снаружи надо для того чтобы, вдруг там было два человека, один вышел а второй остался и нажал на кнопку. А еще до того момента как лифт довез первого, кто-то снаружи нажал вызов лифта. Честно говоря нужны были бы подсказки от интевьюера или говорить что "еще есть над чем подумать но мы не скажем, у нас такой формат" ,на все вопросы отвечалось как хочешь. Казалось будто что все правильно.

Comment: Тут уже как повезет. Возможно вы задавали не те вопросы, возможно интервтювер был недостаточно хорош. Но, судя по постановке задачи, это чисто задачка на алгоритм, тут не надо ни solid, ни паттернов, хотя иметь читабельный и понятный код на выходе это бонус. Ваше решение спотыкается, как мне кажется, именно о реальное время. Это надо было прямо явно проговорить, чтобя не было недоразумений. Просьба подтянуть алгоритмы - это стандартная отписка,. Большие компании редко сообщают конкретные причины отказа. По крайней мере по моему опыту.

Comment: В любом случае, не расстраивайтесь. Я проходил через то же самое много раз. От 3 до 6 месяцев тратил на подготовку, потом пачки собеседований, и отказы с подобными формулировками. Нужно понимать, что даже если вы готовы на 100%, всегда что то может пойти не так (в моем случае так и случалось). Потом ходишь и прокручиваешь в голове задачи, думаешь где же ты свернул не туда. Вам скорее всего сказали, когда вы сможете еще раз попробовать, просто прдготовьтесь, порешайте задачки (мне стало комфортно где то после 1000 решеных задачек), и сможете еще попытаться.

Answer (score 1):

Фраза о реальном времени в условии, думаю, предполагает, что нужно уметь принимать новые команды в то время, как текущая(ие) уже выполняется(ются). Т.е. подход "прочитать команду - выполнить" не годится. Нужно оптимизировать работу лифта учитывая новые поступившие команды. С точки зрения алгоритмов в таком понимании задача гораздо интереснее и сложнее.

Comment: Как можно в многопоточном режиме и принимать и отображать что-то в консоли, при условии что консоль одна, она либо принимать либо отображает.

Comment: System.in and System.out сказали использовать. Консоль одна.

Comment: например, при движении лифта другой человек тоже может вызвать лифт

Answer (score 0):

Я лично думаю, что надо бы почитать SOLID и паттерны. И сделать по первому принципу единственной ответственности. А паттерн посмотреть в сторону Command и прочих поведенческих. Почему то у вас сам лифт и ожидает команды и двигается. Сделайте так чтоб с минимальными изменениями программа могла получать команды из файла из консоли из космоса. По поводу алгоритмов я не думаю что они исходили из этой задачи.

Comment: Так то у меня один час был, к тому же при чем тут паттерны и солид, они сказали что слабые знания алгоритмов

Comment: И это после рефакторинга,  интервьюер сказал что можно не рефакторить, как бы сильно не повлияет на что-то

Comment: Ну я постарался ответить. Но я не был там и не могу судить с каких домыслов он пришёл к такому выводу.

Comment: А так да, с паттернами выглядело бы логичнее

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал задание по другому. Сделал бы класс лифт, от которого наследуются 2 класса кнопки вызова на этаж, и кнопки в самой кабине. У лифта будет только один метод - двигаться(вверх или вниз). все принимаемые команды от кнопок, загонять в какой-нибудь стек и выполнять по очереди.Если направление движения совпадает с вызовом, остановиться на этом этаже, и удалить из стэка.